# Regex - Match string that with : and space

Tags: regex, perl

I have below possible strings and i need to match specific chars.

Possible String to match:

```
dsg.1.2.3.4.5.6.7.5 = STRING: 1234 blah blah blah

OR

dsg.1.2.3.4.5.6.7.5 = STRING: "1234 blah blah blah"
```

Below is the Regex that i have tried. It is working but for the 1st string, It is matching with " "

```
\=\s*STRING\:\s(?=\")\"([^"]*)|([^:]*$)
```

To match the above possible string, I used if condition that match well for the `dsg.1.2.3.4.5.6.7.5 = STRING: "1234 blah blah blah"`

Not the `dsg.1.2.3.4.5.6.7.5 = STRING: 1234 blah blah blah`

Output issue after match:

```
2.  [29-58] ` 1234 blah blah blah`
```

output needed:

```
1.  [29-58] `1234 blah blah blah` --> No space
```

Please help me on this issue.

Comment: That looks like the output from `snmpwalk`. If you're running SNMP queries, you should really use a module like [SNMP.pm](https://metacpan.org/pod/SNMP) or [Net::SNMP](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SNMP).

Comment: This `( [^"]* )` will always match, the or/alternation will never match. This assertion `(?= \" ) \"` will always be true, why is it there? If it's not true, nothing will match. None of those literals need to be escaped. Why not show the perl code you're using. And `No space` = `[^\s]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In perl (PCRE) you can use a regex using `(?|...)` non-capturing group construct:

```
/=\s*STRING:\s(?|"([^"]*)|([^:]*))/
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yN7oT9/2)

`(?|...)` - Subpatterns declared within each alternative of this construct will start over from the same index.

This regex will match `1234 blah blah blah` in the captured group #1 for both input lines.

Comment: @revo: Thanks for fixing my typo in answer.

Answer (score 7):

Try this regular expression:

```
=\s*STRING:\s("?)([^"]*)\1
```

There is no need to use look-aheads, just use `("?)` to match the quote (if it exists) and then use a backreference to match it again in the end. The string after `STRING` will be stored in `$2`.

Comment: Thanks. But it always matches two items.

Comment: @Yadheendran What do you mean? What two items?

Comment: Yes. The string stored in $2.

Comment: You can also use: `=\s*STRING:\s"?([^"]*)`